# Typescript with mocha - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to make a simple test to get to know unit tests using mocha.

**Folder Structure**

- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- testA.ts
- testA.spec.ts
- tsconfig.json

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "target": "ES2019",    
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "unittest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.22",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^10.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "sinon": "^12.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "mocha": {
    "check-leaks": true,
    "globals": [
      "crypto"
    ],
    "recursive": true,
    "spec": [
      "./*.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

**testA.spec.ts**

```
import * as chai from 'chai'

const expect = chai.expect

describe('First Test', () => {
  it('should run the test', () => {
    const a = 12
    expect(a).to.be.equal(12)
    
  })
})
```

When I run `npm test`, I get the follow error.

> /home/user/dev/unitTest/node_modules/@babel/core/src/config/files/index-browser.ts:1
> import type { Handler } from "gensync";
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tried everything I could find searching on the internet but still unable to solve this one.

Comment: You've _installed_ `ts-node`, but don't see to be _using_ it: https://mochajs.org/#-require-module-r-module

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe. Adding `--require ts-node/register` doesn't change the result unfortunately.

Comment: Adding it _where_, though? Did you compare your setup to the linked working TypeScript Mocha setup? Give a [mre] - I get that error _in `testA.spec.ts`_ from what you've posted, and it goes away if I use `"require": ["ts-node/register"]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added to my test script. Then I copied the `.mocharc.yaml` from the [mochajs/mocha-examples](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha-examples/blob/master/packages/typescript/.mocharc.json). Now I get `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

Comment: Then please [edit] your question with an up-to-date [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. Inside `package.json` I added the **require** for mocha:

```json
"devDependencies":{...},
"mocha": {
    "require": [
      "support/ts-node-register.js"
    ],
```

**ts-node-register.js**

```js
const tsNode = require('ts-node');
tsNode.register({
  files: true,
});
```